# ReferenceError: channel is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to know why did I get this error ... I may sound bad but I really do not understand! T-T

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    let welcome = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel.name === "〢〘〙ιsᥴᥙssιoᥒ").send(`Coucou ! <@!${user.id}>`)
}),
```

Comment: .find accepts a callback method so pass - check the part inside the .find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `channel =>`  function argument declaration in the `find` call.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  let welcome = member.guild.channels.cache
    .find((channel) => channel.name === "〢〘〙ιsᥴᥙssιoᥒ")
    .send(`Coucou ! <@!${user.id}>`);
});
```

Comment: but i want to add the ID of the channel and not the name. How i can replace ?

Comment: If you want to find a channel by `id` instead of `name`, use: ``find((channel) => channel.id === "727681043980877844")`` (just an exaple id, you can make it whatever you want)

Comment: `Collection.get()` should be used instead of `Collection.find()` if you are getting the channel by ID because the channels are mapped by ID.